# ng2-charts customization of 'bar' type

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I need a very simple chart like this
[image]

I know how to do that with chart.js

```
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

, but looks like it's not so easy with ng2-charts. I have this

```
<canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="[{data: [65, 59, 80], label: 'Series A'}]"
        [labels]="[['Eingezahlte', 'Beiträge'], ['Guthaben', 'heute'], ['Guthaben nach', 'Rückzahlung']]"
        [chartType]="'bar'">
</canvas>
```

[image]

1) I need different colors
2) align problems (when I fix long labels by separating them to arrays)

***UPDATE***
finally I come with this

```
<canvas baseChart
   [datasets]="barChartData"
   [labels]="['']"
   [chartType]="'bar'"
   [legend]="false"
   [options]="options"
>
</canvas>
public barChartData:any[] = [
        {
            data: ['7000'], label: 'Eingezahlte Beiträge'
        },
        {
            data: ['6000'], label: 'Guthaben heute'
        },
        {
            data: ['10000'], label: 'Guthaben nach Rückzahlung'
        }
    ];

    public options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5,
                    // Create scientific notation labels
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value + ' €';
                    }
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                categoryPercentage: 1.0,
                barPercentage: 0.6
            }]
        }
    };
```

The only problem left is that I want labels at the bottom, but I can do it with html

[image]

Comment: arent you missing the `series`   argument?

Comment: @Blauhirn you are right, updated the question, but still has a problem with the same color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem about the colors lies within your definition of your datasets.
Instead of

```
[datasets]="[{data: [65, 59, 80], label: 'Series A'}]"
```

it really should be

```
[datasets]="[{data: [65], label: 'Series A'},
             {data: [59], label: 'Series B'},
             {data: [80], label: 'Series C'}]
```

This way you can achieve different colors because every dataset has its own color.

Comment: I tried it, in that case I have all 3 bars for the first label. On the first picture you can see that it's different colors for the same dataset, you can add backgroundColor property to your dataset attr in chart.js, but it's not working with ng2-charts

Comment: I think what you are asking for is not possible. [This issue](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/251#issuecomment-225310934) describes the color options for bar charts in ng2-chart. As I see it you can only color individual datasets, not data points within one dataset. But if you are worried about duplicate labels, you might want to consider the following: `[datasets]="[{data: [65], label: 'Eingezahlte Beiträge'}, ...]"`

Comment: I don't care about duplicates, check the last image I uploaded

Comment: This should be fixed by changing your code to `[labels]="[' ']"`

Comment: now I have a problem with scale, Y starts from min value, so I can't see one of my bars (last screen)

Comment: solved with 'yAxes: [{ ticks: { beginAtZero:true}}]' Still not the same what I wanted, cause I can't see labels at the bottom, but I can live with it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe the response to [this issue](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/132#issuecomment-272781578) provides some useful information. You could try to use: `yAxes: [{id: 'y-axis-1', type: 'linear', position: 'left', ticks: {min: 0, max:100}}]` to adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to include [colors]

and then

```
private colors = [
{
  backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)',
    'rgba(102, 0, 204, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 128, 0, 0.2)'
  ]
}
];
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/0lxpDg?p=preview

Source :https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/606